# talking child view controller to child view controller within container view in Swift

Tags: swift, uicontainerview

I have 2 view controllers that get displayed in my container view, I would like to be able to switch views and pass an ID number from one view into another by a button inside the first view controller. How can you change the displayed view controller from inside the child view controller?

Comment: No different than any other case of passing data between controllers. Delegates and protocols is one choice.

Comment: I dont understand how to make the segue happen from the child view controller, it keeps leaving container view when I try to perform a segue.